# How to Prevent / Avoid Brute Force Attack on AJAX Call to ASPX Page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, brute-force

I have an asp.net web application(old aspx).

A page(1) display number and on button click, It makes AJAX request to another aspx page(2) with number displayed on 1st page and get response. if number is not valid, response would have error message as invalid number.

Now, 
2 Page can be requested through any script using loop find valid number.
In 1st page number can be modified through Developer tool and send request to 2nd page.

This cause brute force attack on 2nd page.

2nd page may be accessed by our another application.

Whether Anti Forgery Token could be implemented for this case. 
I could not find any example for old ASPX.

In this context, Please advice how to prevent Brute Force Attack on 2nd page using any approach.

My Ajax Request

```
var data = ({ No: $('#No').text(), xyz: $('#xyz').text()});
        $.ajax({
            url: 'x.aspx?y=z',
            data: Data,
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.startsWith('eRROR')) {
            //Reading and assigning error message to html control
                }
                else {
                    if (data == "Success") {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                //set value to HTML control
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert 
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Lots of options, one don't use a small number, use a very large random string (if it is 100 characters long and each character can be one of 62 values for example, that will take MUCH longer to brute force). Add throttling. If people are doing what they're supposed to, they should never have a "bad" number. So after 10 bad numbers, block them for X minutes. That will make it take days/weeks to brute force.

Comment: Thanks for your timely response. It is a business key, which I cant change. Let me check throttling. I think there is throttling extension for IIS. Please throw light on Throttling, How it can be implemented on old apsx application where Ajax call to aspx file(not web service)

Comment: There are many ways to implement throttling. One way would be, each time someone fails, log it to some data structure. If you see more than X fails in Y seconds, reject additional attempts. Then have some process that cleans out that data structure so that data older than Y seconds isn't stored for ever.

Comment: To Implement throttling, I found Dynamic IP Restrictions extension for IIS and has provision to restrict request with same IP Address and specific period of time.                                                                                       If a hacker know this time period based restriction they can over come this by delayed request right.  In addition, it is applied to all application hosted in IIS. Whether we write our own logic or use extension, we would have this problem. Is there any way to over come this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use GUID instead of a simple (sequential?) number. I'm guessing the number that you display on first page, is the internal ID of the record, which is probably generated as a sequential number by your DB and is very easy to guess.

The solution is to add a GUID column in your table. If you are using SQL server for DB, then GUID is a long, random string, which is not in sequential order.

After generating the GUID, on first page you should use the GUID instead of the id and pass it to the second page. The second page has to look up the GUID to find the ID.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is a business key which I cant change to GUID.